# how to make an associative array in php

Tags: php

I'm beginner in using PHP and I have this string to concantenate using an associative array, i have an idea but it will use an array within an array here is the code by the way

```
$GLOBALS['batman'] = /*** Find the appropriate associative array. ***/;

function robin()
{

   $z = 'flash';
   return $z;
}

function ironman()
{ 
   $answer = $GLOBALS['batman']['superman']['spiderman'][robin()][0]; // "The sum is " - this is a string 
   $answer .= $GLOBALS['batman']['superman']['spiderman'][robin()][1] // 14 - this is an integer
        + $GLOBALS['batman']['superman']['spiderman'][robin()]['hulk'][2];  // 11 - this is an     integer
   return $answer;
}

echo ironman(); // this should print out "The sum is 25"
```

Comment: When you're a beginner you should definitely not use `$GLOBALS` at all; and while you learn more about it, you will realise that you don't ever need it either.

Comment: actually this is my seatwork for my subj and this is the first time I will learn PHP and my prof give this exercise and I am also confused about this globals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is to send back to your "professor" as an example of the kind of code you could be passing to students instead. The mere mention of things like `$GLOBALS` should be eradicated from all textbooks; learning how to pass variables into a function is much more useful.

```
<?php

error_reporting(~0);

function robin()
{
   $z = 'flash';
   return $z;
}

function ironman(array $data)
{ 
  return sprintf('%s%d',
    $data['batman']['superman'][robin()][0],
    $data['batman']['superman'][robin()][1] + $data['batman']['superman'][robin()]['hulk'][2]
  );
}

$data = array(); // fill in appropriate data structure here
echo ironman($data); // this should print out "The sum is 25"
```

Now, when you run this code, you will get hints from the interpreter as to what's missing:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: batman in assoc.php on line 15
```

It means that the `$data` array is missing the `'batman'` index; this is how you add it:

```
$data = array(
  'batman' => array(),
);
```

Running it again will show the following:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: superman in assoc.php on line 15
```

That means your `$data['batman']` array is missing the `'superman'` index; so you add the missing index as well:

```
$data = array(
  'batman' => array(
    'superman' => array(),
  ),
);
```

Basically you keep changing the structure until the interpreter stops complaining and that should also give the right answer.